# Cppcheck errors are not getting reported in SonarQube 7.9.5 using Sonar-cxx community plugin v1.3.3

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, cppcheck

I am having SonarQube Community Edition (v7.9.5) server running with sonar-cxx community plugin v1.3.3

Now for a test C++ project, I have generated cppcheck (v2.3) analysis report and ran sonar-scanner (https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-4.5.0.2216-linux.zip) as follows.

```
$ pwd
/testproj

$ ls
file1.cc

$ cat file1.cc 
int main()
{
    char a[10];
    a[10] = 0;
    return 0;
}

$ cppcheck --enable=all --xml . 2> cppcheck_issues.xml

$ cat cppcheck_issues.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results version="2">
    <cppcheck version="2.3"/>
    <errors>
        <error id="arrayIndexOutOfBounds" severity="error" msg="Array &apos;a[10]&apos; accessed at index 10, which is out of bounds." verbose="Array &apos;a[10]&apos; accessed at index 10, which is out of bounds." cwe="788" hash="11923574308940205340">
            <location file="file1.cc" line="4" column="2" info="Array index out of bounds"/>
        </error>
        <error id="unreadVariable" severity="style" msg="Variable &apos;a[10]&apos; is assigned a value that is never used." verbose="Variable &apos;a[10]&apos; is assigned a value that is never used." cwe="563" hash="9507758794529763218">
            <location file="file1.cc" line="4" column="7"/>
            <symbol>a[10]</symbol>
        </error>
    </errors>
</results>

$ sonar-scanner \
    -Dsonar.host.url=<sonar-host-url>\
    -Dsonar.login=<sonar-token>\
    -Dsonar.projectName=testproj\
    -Dsonar.projectKey=testproj\
    -Dsonar.projectVersion=0.1\
    -Dsonar.cxx.cppcheck.reportPath=cppcheck_issues.xml\
    -Dsonar.exclusions=cppcheck_issues.xml
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /code/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarScanner 4.5.0.2216
INFO: Java 11.0.3 AdoptOpenJDK (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 4.1.12-124.43.4.el7uek.x86_64 amd64
INFO: User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /code/sonar-scanner/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 7.9.5
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=142ms
INFO: Server id: 22633092-AXeMotAnTu7ckErSxqZC
INFO: User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load/download plugins
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=73ms
INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=141ms
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Execute project builders
INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=9ms
INFO: Project key: testproj
INFO: Base dir: /testproj
INFO: Working dir: /testproj/.scannerwork
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'testproj'
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'testproj' (done) | time=74ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=99ms
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=1167ms
WARN: SCM provider autodetection failed. Please use "sonar.scm.provider" to define SCM of your project, or disable the SCM Sensor in the project settings.
INFO: Indexing files...
INFO: Project configuration:
INFO:   Excluded sources: cppcheck_issues.xml
INFO: 1 file indexed
INFO: 0 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
INFO: Quality profile for c++: Sonar way
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on module testproj
INFO: Load metrics repository
INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=41ms
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/root/.sonar/cache/866bb1adbf016ea515620f1aaa15ec53/sonar-javascript-plugin.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
INFO: Sensor C++ (Community) SquidSensor [cxx]
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=31ms
INFO: Sensor C++ (Community) SquidSensor [cxx] (done) | time=312ms
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=9ms
INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java]
INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java] (done) | time=3ms
INFO: Sensor HTML [web]
INFO: Sensor HTML [web] (done) | time=23ms
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on project
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=27ms
INFO: No SCM system was detected. You can use the 'sonar.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it.
INFO: 1 file had no CPD blocks
INFO: Calculating CPD for 0 files
INFO: CPD calculation finished
INFO: Analysis report generated in 157ms, dir size=79 KB
INFO: Analysis report compressed in 22ms, zip size=12 KB
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 58ms
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse <sonar-host-url>/dashboard?id=testproj
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
INFO: More about the report processing at <sonar-host-url>/api/ce/task?id=AXeQLS1KTu7ckErSxt5M
INFO: Executing post-job 'Final report'
INFO: Turn debug info on to get more details (sonar-scanner -X -Dsonar.verbose=true ...).
INFO: Analysis total time: 5.510 s
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 7.283s
INFO: Final Memory: 12M/44M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now the project is successfully created/updated in SonarQube; but, the issues are not reported in SonarQube. Someone would be able to suggest on what could be the reason?
[Please refer the snapshot of the project in SonarQube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dtpkz.png)

Note-1: sonar.cxx.suffixes.sources is configured to ".cc" value for C++ (Community) plugin in SonarQube server configuration. And, there are no other plugin seen present with the same configuration key.

Note-2: There are no errors/warnings seen in ce.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue cause is found after doing some more digging.

Issue cause: The default quality profile corresponding to the C++ (Community) had their all rules disabled by default, and there was no option to enable them as well.

Fix: Created a new quality profile extending the default one, then enabled rules for that, and finally made it as the default quality profile for C++ (Community) solves the issue.

Update (16-Feb-'21): Got a clarification from sonar-cxx team that this is intentional as well, and the same is documented in https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/wiki/Manage-Quality-Profiles

> Since the cxx plugin contains a large number of sensors with over 4000
> rules, all rules are initially deactivated in the default profile
> Sonar way for the programming language CXX. Enabling all rules would
> have a negative impact on the analysis performance and mostly only a
> subset is needed.
>
> Therefore, after installation, no sensor issues are displayed. To
> display issues, the corresponding rules must first be enabled in the
> Quality Profile being used by the project.